# how do I create an extension method for a single specific enum

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I've got an enum class full of command line switches for a third party app..I'm trying to make it so I can call on an item in the enum with a .ToSwitch (or whatever) so that I can make it validate the value  type, spit out a formatted command-line switch with its parameter value.  maybe I'm going about it wrong. After sitting here all day working on it (it's big) I'm finding it hard to let go and explore a different approach. lol any suggestions?

desired result:

```
Console.WriteLine(EnumClass.EnumItem.ToSwitch("option"));
```

would spit out: -x "option"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a specific enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    value1 = 1,
    value2 = 2,
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToSwitch(this MyEnum val, string option)
    {
        switch (val)
        {
            case MyEnum.value1 : return "x " + option;
            case MyEnum.value2 : return "y " + option;
            default: return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to do what you're talking about is with a `Dictionary`, which might be preferable. The keys would be the switch (or the enum value), and value would be the command format. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> CmdFormats = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "-a", "filename" },
    { "-n", "number" }
};
```

I suspect that would be more maintainable than defining an enum.